# Issue of oozie while launching job

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

The command :

```
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:8080/oozie -config /home/hadoop/Desktop/Cloudera/oozie-2.3.0-cdh3u1/examples/apps/no-op/job.properties -run
```

Error message:

```
Error: IO_ERROR : java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Comment: Is the oozie service running?

Comment: Yes oozie service is running .
$ oozie admin -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -status
System mode: NORMAL

$ oozie admin -oozie http://localhost:8080/oozie -status
Error: IO_ERROR : java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

When i am using port number 11000. the status is normal. But with 8080 (i.e my localhost port) and without it ,it's coming connection refused .

I am new to oozie.

Comment: Is it running on 11000 or 8080? A connection refused typically means that no one is listening.

Comment: <property>
        <name>oozie.base.url</name>
        <value>http://localhost:8080/oozie</value>
        <description>
             Base Oozie URL.
        </description>
    </property>

This is my setting in default-site.xml.

My web console is enable on port 11000.

8080 is my base URL for Oozie workflow jobs

Comment: @Steve I have configured the problem. I needed to add 2 lines in conf file and run it on port no.- 11000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I configured the oozie

**Steps**

1. Add this line in core-site.xml in hadoop conf

   **hadoop.proxyuser.xxx.hosts    *        hadoop.proxyuser.xxx.groups    ***

   Here, xxx - User name
2. Save the conf file and run the code

   oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config /home/hadoop/Desktop/Cloudera/oozie-2.3.0-cdh3u1/examples/apps/no-op/job.properties -run

Comment: what username? is it the root or a separate user name for oozie?

Comment: can you check this if you know how to resolve this - http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/oozie-user/201306.mbox/%3CCAPbOs9sET_Wca7nKeEBD2_QtmMqsUr%2B3C3d8tu09u0Bfyo70TQ%40mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: @Debaditya The core-site.xml is a well formatted XML file, right? Where does your one line goes to? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It took me 2 days to fix this error. In my case I had 4 Nodes. Oozie was configured in Node 4. But I kept on running the command to name-node which was N1 or hive server which was N3. So make sure you are running command against Oozie server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not an Admin make sure you are invoking the oozie client from the correct node. Use `localhost` only if you are connecting the client from the machine where the oozie server is running. If you are a developer like me who is connecting from an edge node make sure you are exporting the correct URL of oozie the server.

I had a similar problem in my cluster(CDH 5.3.6) running on AWS. I was trying to export the OOZIE_URL just with the host name and port like below

```
[user@ip-10-241-1-164 ~]$ export OOZIE_URL=http://10.241.1.164:11000/oozie
```

but it was throwing the same error. It did not like the host name. Finally I have navigated to the Oozie section (find the steps at the end) in Hue and found the oozie.servers value

```
oozie.servers
value   ip-10-241-1-111.ec2.internal=http://ip-10-241-1-111.ec2.internal:11000/oozie
```

copied the value and changed the export command like this

```
[user@ip-10-241-1-164 ~]$ export OOZIE_URL=http://ip-10-241-1-111.ec2.internal:11000/oozie
```

and that has fixed my issue.

How to find the oozie.servers value:

- Open Hue and go to Workflows
- Navigate to Oozie

[image: Screen shot from Hue]

- Under **gauges** scroll down until you see oozie.servers name
- Copy the value and you are done.